# How to generate C (native) header file from .class file (complied)

Tags: java, class, java-native-interface, header-files

I am in need of generating a `.h` file from a `.class` file using OpenJDK-11 on *Windows 10*. The IDE is *IntelliJ 2018-2*.

When using `javac -h`, it gives me the error below:

```
javac -h dest.h -classpath <'classes location'> <package>
```

**Error:**

> error: Class names, 'package', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested
>   1 error

Comment: Hi, I get the same error. Did you resolve it?